# How do I run an update query in MySQL on a CTE?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, common-table-expression, window-functions

I'm trying to create a CTE, which I think is working fine. However, I want to then run an update query on this CTE but I keep getting the following error in MySQL WorkBench,

```
"Error Code: 1288. The target table pptest of the UPDATE is not updatable"
```

I've had a look around but no not understand any of the work arounds and on top of that I'm not too clued up on my MySQL either. My goal was basically to create a table/view with a bunch of records in there that were partitioned and would have an index number on each row, which would be represented by "row_num". This was to group duplicated data in a table together and then I was hoping to simply run an update query on this structure where the row_num was greater than 1. So simple logic but I cannot figure out any other way of achieving my goal. Can anyone help with this please?

The full query I ran before was,

```
WITH cte as (select *, row_number() over (partition by col_a order by col_a) row_num from db_name.table_name) 
update cte set col_b='test' where row_num > 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax is not supported in MySQL. Actually this looks like SQL Server syntax... You can't just port queries from one database to another and expect them to work.

In MySQL, you could use the `update ... join` syntax. However, you need a primary key column (or set of columns), that uniquely identifies each row, to serve as a join condition. Assuming that column `id` is your primary key, that would be:

```
update db_name.table_name t
inner join (
    select id
    row_number() over (partition by col_a order by col_a) row_num 
    from db_name.table_name) 
) t1 on t1.id = t.id
set t.col_b = 'test' 
where t1.row_num > 1
```

Side notes:

- As I understand this, your query is meant to flag duplicates on `col_a`. But the way you use `row_number()`, it is undefined which of the duplicate rows will be flagged, because your `order by` clause is not deterministic; you would better have an `over()` clause like: `over (partition by col_a order by id)`
- window functions such as `row_number()` are available in MySQL 8.0 only

Answer (score 0):

Update and Delete not work in mysql temporary table. A work around is to join the original table with temporary table CTE and update original table :

```
    WITH cte as (select *, row_number() 
over (partition by col_a order by col_a) row_num 
from db_name.table_name) 
    
    update db_name.table_name T1 
Join 
cte on T1.col_a = cte.col_a set t1.col_b='test' where cte.row_num > 1
```

this work fine for delete instruction too.